# How to asign controller to Textformfield when they are inside Listview builder?

Tags: flutter

[image]

There is a plus sign on top that is used to add textfields. The user can add up to seven text files at once, or any number between three and seven. Three text fields are already present and cannot be deleted. So, how can I assign controllers to those additional fields so that the data contained within them can be used in the post method, and all other textfields will have the different value? For example, there are three textfields, and if I enter 'My name is robot' in one, it is automatically entered in the other two. How can I handle this such that the same text is not automatically typed in the other two?

Comment: What do you mean by "post" method?

Comment: instead of those two use `controller: ...`

Comment: @pskink, ok how do I assign controller to every fields ?

Comment: make a list of controllers, a list of up to 7 controllers, and simply do `controller: list[i]` where `i` is index of `ListView.builder`